# A tag with href not receiving keyboard focus on tab

Tags: accessibility, keyboard-focus

I'm working on a menu with links, the structure is ul > li > a tag with href, and the links are not receiving focus on tabbing through the menu. As far as I'm aware the default behaviour of an a tag with a valid href is to receive keyboard focus on tab. Is this an OS/browser issue? I'm on Mac running Catalina and browsing in Chrome.

```
<ul class="collapse" id="footerLinksHelp">
        <li class="footer-links__item">
            <a href="https://help.com" class="footer-links__link" title="Go to Delivery" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Delivery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="footer-links__item">
            <a href="https://help.com" class="footer-links__link" title="Go to Returns" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Returns</a>
        </li>
        <li class="footer-links__item">
            <a href="https://orders.com" class="footer-links__link" title="Check my Order">Check my Order</a>
        </li>
        <li class="footer-links__item">
            <a href="https://terms.com" class="footer-links__link" title="Go to Terms" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="footer-links__item">
            <a href="https://customer-support.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Customer
                Support</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I've googled this and read through accessibility docs but can't figure out why the a tags are not receiving any keyboard focus. This is an accessibility requirement identified by testing.

Comment: Hi Natalie, an luck?

Comment: Yes as it happens, someone else in my team had placed code in a bootstrap overrides file that added: outline: 0px !important; to a tags with focus, thus obviously overruling the default behaviour as well as any styling rules I was attempting to apply in my file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `tabindex=0` attribute to your link (anchor tag). Your browser can cause issues like this sometimes but that can't be determined from the above snippet.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I was aware of tabindex="0", but didn't think it was required on natively focusable elements such as a tags, I've used it before on div or span elements. As you mention this could be caused by the browser though.